# How to fetch all distinct rows, SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, unique

Here's my table:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table entry (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "date text not null, " +
        "velocity integer not null, " +
        "type text not null, " +
        "xCoord real not null, " +
        "yCoord real not null, " +
        "color integer not null);";
```

My listView is populated by dates, when the entries were created. So my listView looks something like this:

```
December 25, 2011
December 25, 2011
December 25, 2011
December 26, 2011
December 26, 2011
December 27, 2011
```

So basically, every time an entry is saved in the database, it will display the date when it was created. I managed to select unique date, so the same date will only show once, by doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM entry GROUP BY date
```

Now my listView looks like this:

```
December 25, 2011
December 26, 2011
December 27, 2011
```

My question is, when I click on a row in the listView, how can I fetch all rows which have the same date as the one I clicked on. For example, If I click on "December 25, 2011" then I want the query to return all information of those 3 rows which have that same date I clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM entry WHERE date='December 25, 2011'`

Comment: Well this is the correct answer to my example, but it's a little bit more complicated than that. I want to be able to click on any date and get all the information to whatever date I clicked on.

Comment: This only gives me the information from December 25, 2011. I don't know which date the user wants to look at.

Comment: Er, don't they want to look at December 25, 2011?  How is that not the date they clicked on?  I don't understand the distinction.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand where we're talking past each other.  You want to know how to map a `ListView` element onto a date so then you can use the date to populate your database query.  The question is more about how to use a `ListView` than it is about database queries.  Do I have it right?

Comment: Well, I need a query that works for all dates. So let's say that there are 100 dates in the listView which you can click on and view. I'm never going to know which date the user clicks on, right? So, I need a query that can work with whichever date the user clicks on in the listView and show the entries that he created that day. Yeah, I don't know how I can make the listView know which date the user clicks on.

Comment: The click listener that's activated will tell you which element was selected.  Use that information to construct the appropriate query string.  `String q = String.format("SELECT * FROM entry WHERE date='%s'", theDate);`

Answer (score 0):

Your DB structure is just a little bit, maybe, against the db theory. You maybe better have 2 tables, to avoid  data repetition. This way you display 1st table in the list and in this table all the data (dates) are distinct. Then, when user clicks you fetch whatever records have the same data key from the second table and you can then display all the other stuff from those fetched rows in the 2nd table

Comment: That's a good idea. I tried having two seperate tables, one with just column date and the other one exactly like mine is above. Then I was populating the listView with the table that contains only the dates, but I wasn't 100% for sure how to join these tables. I tried full join and it wouldn't work. Any ideas?